# Conflict between image and algorithm style

Tags: graphics, floats, algorithms

I'm trying to write an article with both figures and algorithms. The commands related to images should be these:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{caption}
\restylefloat{figure}
```

Instead, the code related to algorithms should be this:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

Here's the problem: before introducing these last commands for pseudocode, the style for images was the figure alone with a caption that had a lower width than the rest of the text, while after introducing these lines images basically adopted the same graphical style of the algorithms:

[image: Figure with algorithm's graphical style]

Do you know what I could do to get back standard figures' graphical style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, add a MWE instead of just code snippets. People here then can reproduce your problem and try to help you.

Comment: While we want to help you, somehow, I failed to understand the problem even after several readings. Use of "Instead" at the start of second paragraph complicated the comprehension further. Please provide an MWE. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, but the answer solved the problem. Next time, I will provide an MWE! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to simply remove the line

```
\restylefloat{figure}
```

In fact, you should have something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{caption}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output

[image]

Removing that line, you get instead

[image]

The problem arises from the fact that the `algorithm` package redefines the float style to be `ruled` and, when you issue

```
\restylefloat{figure}
```

the `ruled` style is also applied to the `figure` float.

---

If, for some reason, you have to keep that line in your document, the solution is to load `algorithm` after that line.